# Cluster service shared resource in C#

Tags: c#, windows-services, cluster-computing

I noticed, when setting up a generic service (my C# service) in a cluster configuration, it assigns a shared resource (`$T`).

What's the best way to share configurations between both server nodes, while keeping the service applicable for non-cluster enviroments?

Currently the service uses an XML settings file that is in the services local directory.

A favorable solution, would be that the service is aware of a cluster envoriment and then uses the shared resource. I'm not sure if this is achievable.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the configuration in a resource that is handled by the cluster. You can store the config file on a disk partition that belongs to the same resource group as your service. I think that it is also possible to mark registry keys as clustered so that they are automatically replicated between the cluster nodes.

Comment: Thanks. My intentions were to use the resource handled by the cluster , but was looking for a way for the  C# service to use it automaticly rather then configured.